# Http Header Field in @Bean Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot version 2.0.5. I have a `@Bean` method to create request scopes beans but to create the instance I need to access the http header fields of the request I create the instance for. The `@RequestHeader` annotation works fine in my `@RestController` but not in my `@Bean` method. Does anyone know how to access that information in that context?

Below is an example of what I would like to do but as it does not work as the `@RequestHeader` annotation does not work in that contest.

Thank you for any hint.

Best regards, Dominic

```
@Configuration
public class AProducer {

@Bean
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public User produceUser( @RequestHeader(value="Accept") String acceptType ) {
    ....
    }

}
```

Comment: You can autowire the HttpServletRequest in your bean, and extract the header from it. Maybe there is another way, but that one at least should work fine, and is not too hard.

Answer (score 5):

`@RequestHeader` annotations is only supported on handler methods, from docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html)

```
public @interface RequestHeader
```

**Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request header.
Supported for annotated handler methods in Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux.**

If the method parameter is Map, MultiValueMap, or HttpHeaders then the map is populated with all header names and values.

So get the Header values in web request handler method in `Controller` class and pass it through the method arguments to `produceUser`

Example: This is the method in `Controller Class` which is annotated with either `@Controller` or `@RestController`

```
@RequestMapping("/displayHeaderInfo.do")
public void displayHeaderInfo(@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") String encoding,
                          @RequestHeader("Keep-Alive") long keepAlive)  {
         //call the `produceUser(String reqParam)` method by autowiring `AProducer` class
}
```

or simply you can try `private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;` in `AProducer` class and get headers as suggested by @JB Nizet;

```
@Configuration
public class AProducer {

  private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request

 @Bean
 @Scope(value="request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 public User produceUser( @RequestHeader(value="Accept") String acceptType ) {
....      //String value =request.getHeader("Accept")
     }

 }
```

Comment: I dont get it, sorry! Can you may provide a small example ... does not have to work, just to get an idea?